# Render and save a video file with python

Tags: python, video, graphics, pygame, pyglet

I want to use python to generate a video of some 2d geometric objects (circles, squares, ...) that are moving around.

I suspect the solution could be using a library like pygame, piglet for the render and then save screenshot and append to video file using some other library.

Importantly I need to do this without having a screen/window opened; basically pyagme or piglet should write an image on some buffer instead of screen.

I had some success using matplotlib, but I feel like it is not the most appropriate tool for this project, especially if I want to make the graphics more fancy and want to have something that runs fast.

EDIT:
I ended up using command line tools like ffmpeg

Comment: this depends on what graphical backend you will use. I can't say for GL, but if you you use numpy arrays or pygame surfaces, for example, you just write-append your resulting array/image as a byte string and then convert the whole thing with ffmpeg (see Torxed's answer) into a video file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you made a search online and ended up here hoping for a one-liner to do this, I'm afraid you won't find this here. However, this might point you in the right direction.

In pyglet, and most of the GL libraries for Python you won't find a pre-created API to generate video streams, however they do however provide a way to get the raw pixel data of each individual frame.

I'll stick to Pyglet because it's by far the fastest library I've tried over the yers and It's my religion.

```
pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save('screenshot.png')
```

This code is not used to save a specific image, rather it's used to grab the entire window and save it to a file called `screenshot.png`.

Use this to create a indexed series of screenshots:

```
frame = 0
def on_draw():
    ...
    pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(str(frame)+'.png')
```

Once you're done running your application simply use any video encoding tool (mencoder, ffmpeg, windows movie maker or w/e) and combine all the stills into a video file.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 0 -r 3 -i %04d.png -s 720x480 test.avi
```

And voila, you should have a `test.avi` video file of your stills.
Now there's better alternatives, such as to pipe the video to ffmpeg each individual frame to save processing time, but to do this you need to interact with ffmpeg right away and there's libraries for this such as https://github.com/kanryu/pipeffmpeg

Comment: hey @torxed, what do you mean by pipe the video to ffmpeg for each individual frame? I'm trying to export a set of pyglet frames into a video, as they run else, I'm getting a delay of 50-100ms per disk frame write. Thanks!

Comment: bit late but that problem can be fixed by saving texture data( .get_texture() ) of the color buffer in a list and then saving image data ( .get_image_data() ) of each texture in a custom on_close() function and then adjusting framerate for ffmpeg it should work

Answer (score 0):

Zengl and ffmpeg are a powerful combination. This example renders at 193fps and creates a video called `test.mp4`, and an image called `hello.png`.

```py
import math
from tqdm import tqdm
import zengl
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import ffmpeg

ctx = zengl.context(zengl.loader(headless=True))

size = (1280, 720)
image = ctx.image(size, 'rgba8unorm', samples=1)
depth = ctx.image(size, 'depth24plus', samples=1)
process2 = ffmpeg \
            .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgba', s='{}x{}'.format(size[0], size[1]), r=60) \
            .vflip() \
            .output("test.mp4", pix_fmt='rgb24', loglevel="quiet", r=60) \
            .overwrite_output() \
            .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)

def grass_mesh():
    a = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 8)
    b = np.square(a)
    c = np.sin(b * (np.pi - 1.0) + 1.0)
    verts = []
    for i in range(7):
        verts.append((-c[i] * 0.03, b[i] * 0.2, a[i]))
        verts.append((c[i] * 0.03, b[i] * 0.2, a[i]))
    verts.append((0.0, 0.2, 1.0))
    verts = ','.join('vec3(%.8f, %.8f, %.8f)' % x for x in verts)
    return 'vec3 grass[15] = vec3[](%s);' % verts

uniform_buffer = ctx.buffer(size=80)

N = 1000

instances = np.array([
    np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, N),
    np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, N),
    np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, N),
    np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, N),
]).T

instance_buffer = ctx.buffer(instances.astype('f4').tobytes())

ctx.includes['grass'] = grass_mesh()

triangle = ctx.pipeline(
    vertex_shader='''
        #version 330
        #include "grass"
        layout (std140) uniform Common {
            mat4 mvp;
        };
        layout (location = 0) in vec4 in_data;
        out vec2 v_data;
        void main() {
            vec3 v = grass[gl_VertexID];
            vec3 vert = vec3(
                in_data.x + cos(in_data.z) * v.x + sin(in_data.z) * v.y,
                in_data.y + cos(in_data.z) * v.y - sin(in_data.z) * v.x,
                v.z
            );
            gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vert, 1.0);
            v_data = vec2(in_data.w, v.z);
        }
    ''',
    fragment_shader='''
        #version 330
        in vec2 v_data;
        layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_color;
        void main() {
            vec3 yl = vec3(0.63, 1.0, 0.3);
            vec3 gn = vec3(0.15, 0.83, 0.3);
            out_color = vec4((yl + (gn - yl) * v_data.x) * v_data.y, 1.0);
        }
    ''',
    layout=[
        {
            'name': 'Common',
            'binding': 0,
        },
    ],
    resources=[
        {
            'type': 'uniform_buffer',
            'binding': 0,
            'buffer': uniform_buffer,
        },
    ],
    framebuffer=[image, depth],
    topology='triangle_strip',
    cull_face='back',
    vertex_buffers=zengl.bind(instance_buffer, '4f /i', 0),
    instance_count=N,
    vertex_count=15,
)

for i in tqdm(range(300)):
    x, y = math.sin(i * 0.01) * 3.0, math.cos(i * 0.01) * 3.0
    camera = zengl.camera((x, y, 2.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.5), aspect=size[0] / size[1], fov=45.0)

    uniform_buffer.write(camera)
    uniform_buffer.write(zengl.pack(x, y, 2.0, 0.0), offset=64)

    image.clear_value = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    image.clear()
    depth.clear()
    triangle.render()
    image.blit()
    process2.stdin.write(
            image.read()
        )
process2.stdin.close()
process2.wait()

Image.frombuffer('RGBA', size, image.read(), 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, -1).save('hello.png')
```

[image]